# submit form event doesn't work! Why?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, submit

I can't give link to project, therefore put example on jsfiddle.

In my project [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/K4VG2/1/) work,

But [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K4VG2/2/) not!

Help please, i want send form by SUBMIT form event!

**UPDATE 1:** I don't know why it not work. Until i write like this :\

```
$('.container input[type="submit"]').click();
```

**UPDATE 2:** Found the problem:
I'm insert second form via jQuery ajax. receiving data contain HTML and style/script for inserting HTML. It script adds TinyMce to textarea element. Likely jQuery \ TinyMce deleted submit event handler.

Comment: but what will happen ?! for me works, or what ?  confuse.

Comment: The way your doing it you can't submit two forms at the same time....

Comment: if i have one form instance on page, then form submit. when i have 2 form is JS submit doesn't work

Comment: You just can't submit two forms at the same time, because the browser wouldn't be able to handle them. You can go north or south, you just can't go north and south at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that. You can do it like this though,

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/K4VG2/2/show">
        <input type="text" name="field1">
        <input type="text" name="field2">
        <input type="text" name="field3">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <button type="button">go</button>
</div>
```

Then, on the server side, where you process the form, you can check which fields were filled and which ones were empty. So, you just use the ones which had content.

Comment: In my project I'm use correct form elements with all fields and properties. talks about server-side until not important. I want know why form don't send? why not work form event?

Comment: @vitaly.batonov: form don't send bcoz form can send once. ya gettiin my gangsta? YOU CANNOT SUBMIT TWO FORMS AT THE SAME TIME! Yo hearing me? Yo gettin me therr? `Вы не можете представить две формы в то же время`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for russian language. if you look closely at the example we can see that the form is sought in ".conteiner" element and we have only one form.

Comment: @Vitaly Batonov: Hmm... you mean if you click the `go` button, it should submit the form within the `.container`, but it is not submitting?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the URL in the action attribute is a correct one (I mean, there is something at this URL). I have noted that when using jQuery to trigger the form submit, if the server returns an error (i.e. Http 404), the request dies silently, without any error or notification to the browser.

But I have checked your code setting the form's action to another URL and it worked OK.